# Serializing Floats in PHP - Unexpected Results

Tags: php, serialization, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm writing a `serialize()` parser/validator, and I ran across this (somewhat unexpected behavior):

```
$float = 875.6745;
echo "serialize({$float}) === " . serialize($float) . "\n";
echo "(float) \"875.67449999999997\" === " . ((float) "875.67449999999997") . "\n";
```

Output:

> serialize(875.6745) === d:875.67449999999997;
>
> (float) "875.67449999999997" === 875.6745

When I serialize a float, the value stored doesn't really match the input, however, when the serialized string is re-`float`ed, the value matches again...

Should I be concerned?

Comment: [Read, learn and inwardly digest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

Comment: So, as to my question.... ? Should I be concerned? (I'm aware of floating point inaccuracy, that's why I applied the tag to my question).

Comment: The answer is .... it depends.... this could cause minor discrepancies if exported on a 32-bit system and imported ona 64-bit system, or vice versa; but in most circumstances it won't cause any issue

Comment: That's what I was hoping for. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you almost certainly don't need to worry.

Long answer: PHP is just printing enough digits to ensure that it can correctly read back the number exactly.

There is no floating point number 875.6745. When you enter the number, it is converted to the IEEE754 binary64 (a.k.a C `double` on most computers today) format, which rounds it to:

875.6744999999999663486960344016551971435546875

When you serialize it, it doesn't print this number (and it doesn't need to): instead it just saves 17 digits, [which is enough to ensure that it can read back the value exactly](http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/).

This conversion should be consistent across most hardware today, and you don't need to worry about 32 vs 64 bit platforms: this has absolutely no bearing on floating point numbers (we've had "native" 64 bit floats since the 16-bit 8086).

(technically, [PHP says that the size of the float is platform dependent](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), but unless you're dealing with [30 year old hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-10), you don't need to worry).